# Java how to execute multiple sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I am getting error on executing a SQL dump data using normal JBDC connection I didn't know what is the reason for getting error: Please help me.

```
try{
      Connection con1=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
     String sql1=jTextArea1.getText();
       PreparedStatement stm1=(PreparedStatement) con1.prepareStatement(sql1);
       stm1.executeUpdate(sql1);

   }
    catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());   
      }
```

data in jTextarea1:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admission`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `admission` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `srno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `studentname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cast` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Religion` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mothername` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `motheroccupation` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fatheroccupation` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localguardian` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anotherno` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nationality` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateofadm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Last_institution` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admfees` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `convamt` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feeschedule` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearlyfee` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_bal` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `sphoto` longblob NOT NULL,
  `bicycle` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdatedon` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
  `monfee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tcharge` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `othercharge` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tcn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `admission` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `admission` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `admission` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bank1`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bank1` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personby` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netamt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `bank1` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank1` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank1` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bank2`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bank2` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personby` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netamt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `bank2` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank2` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank2` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bank3`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bank3` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personby` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netamt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `bank3` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank3` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank3` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cashadd`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `cashadd` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `srno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `cashadd` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cashadd` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cashadd` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cashinhand`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `cashinhand` (
  `cash` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cashbook` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cashbook`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `cashinhand` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cashinhand` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cashinhand` VALUES (0.00,'Head cash book #',1),(0.00,'Main Cash book $',2),(0.00,'P. cash Book *',3);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cashinhand` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `emp`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empCategory` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phoneno` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Qualification` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Experience` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `emp` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `emp` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `emp` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `empcategory`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `empcategory` (
  `Category` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `empcategory` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empcategory` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empcategory` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `emppay`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `emppay` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empcategory` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leave1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netamt` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `work` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pf` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `emppay` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `emppay` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `emppay` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `feesdeposite`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `feesdeposite` (
  `studid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiptno` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_Sec` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noofmonth` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prebalance` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyfees` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `termcharges` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Recieve` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastmonth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastbaldepo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bich` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fine` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paidconv` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `convamt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`receiptno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `feesdeposite` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesdeposite` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesdeposite` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `feesschedule`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `feesschedule` (
  `sno` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noofmonth` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fees` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `termcharges` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `feesschedule` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesschedule` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `feesschedule` VALUES (1,'1 to 10',1,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(2,'1 to 10',2,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(3,'1 to 10',4,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(4,'1 to 10',5,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-A'),(5,'1 to 10',6,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(6,'1 to 10',7,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-A'),(7,'1 to 10',8,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(8,'1 to 10',9,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-A'),(9,'1 to 10',4,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(10,'1 to 10',5,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-B'),(11,'1 to 10',6,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(12,'1 to 10',7,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-B'),(13,'1 to 10',8,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(14,'1 to 10',9,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(15,'1 to 10',10,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(16,'1 to 10',11,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-B'),(17,'1 to 10',1,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(18,'1 to 10',2,2,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(19,'1 to 10',4,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(20,'1 to 10',5,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-C'),(21,'1 to 10',6,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(22,'1 to 10',7,1,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Type-C'),(23,'1 to 10',8,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(24,'1 to 10',9,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(25,'1 to 10',10,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(26,'1 to 10',11,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(27,'1 to 10',12,1,'Yes','Yes','No','Type-C'),(52,'1 to 10',1,3,'Yes','Yes','No','TYPE-D'),(53,'1 to 10',4,3,'Yes','Yes','Yes','TYPE-D'),(54,'1 to 10',7,3,'Yes','Yes','Yes','TYPE-D'),(55,'1 to 10',10,3,'Yes','Yes','No','TYPE-D');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesschedule` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `feesstructure`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `feesstructure` (
  `session` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prospectusfees` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adm` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digital1to8` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digitalpgtoprep` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `generator` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cycle` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `termcharges` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `feesstructure` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesstructure` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `feesstructure` VALUES ('14-15',200.00,200.00,1000.00,400.00,1200.00,1000.00,0.00,0.00,580.00);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `feesstructure` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `head`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `head` (
  `headname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`headname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `head` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `head` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `head` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `headpayment`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `headpayment` (
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payhead` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `advance` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `net` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cashbook` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `headpayment` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `headpayment` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `headpayment` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `login`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `login` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `login` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `login` VALUES ('gacme','gacme'),('jacme','jacme');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `login` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `money_detailer`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `money_detailer` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `income` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iamt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expences` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eamt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `net` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `money_detailer` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `money_detailer` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `money_detailer` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `monthlyfees`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `monthlyfees` (
  `session` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pg` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nursury` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prep` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `1st` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2nd` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `3rd` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `4th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `5th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `6th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `7th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `8th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `9th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `10th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `11th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `12th` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `monthlyfees` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `monthlyfees` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `monthlyfees` VALUES ('14-15',540,540,540,560,560,580,630,660,660,750,750,1125,1200,0,0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `monthlyfees` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `otherpro`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `otherpro` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `otherpro` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `otherpro` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `otherpro` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pendingfee`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `pendingfee` (
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `srno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calsssesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receptno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prebal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cahdepo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `pendingfee` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pendingfee` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pendingfee` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `register`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `register` (
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tnum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `register` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `register` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `register` VALUES (1,25,'2014-04-22'),(0,25,'2014-05-22');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `register` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `session`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `session_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `session` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `session` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `session` VALUES ('14-15',1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `session` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trans`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `transport` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transport`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `trans` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `trans` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `trans` VALUES ('Bus',1,''),('Van',2,'');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `trans` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

i am getting error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COL' at line 2
```

Please help me why i am getting this error and how should i fix this error

Comment: You don't have to ask the same question twice.

Comment: i don't get my answer so i have asked

Comment: I know, and you have to wait for an answer **there**. In the meantime, you can keep searching on how to solve your problem. This is a free advice, so you won't have a myriad of people focusing on your single problem and thinking and writing code for you for free.